# Dynamic reports report generation is fast in eclipse but very slow in exported jar?

Tags: java, performance, jar, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I'm facing a strange issue. i have a subreport generation code using dynamic reports api. when i run the code from within eclipse, it runs very fast. but when i export and make a runnable jar. it it very very slow even if there are no records.

I checked using log that data fetch and other things are good. it's a fat jar having dependencies built in

I saw another thread [Jasper Report Pdf Export in Eclipse ok but from Jar file very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31338435/jasper-report-pdf-export-in-eclipse-ok-but-from-jar-file-very-slow)

here i don't know how to check and set version of java for jasper outside eclipse.

**PS: One more observation**, If i place the required libraries next to my jar, it runs perfect.
What may be wrong with fat jar?

Comment: Did you try to use profiler?

Comment: try using VisualVM to profile it.  It comes with most JDKs

Comment: I jvisualvm, i don't see an issue, i see max heap is sufficient, gc is ok.

Comment: I hope that profiler can help you - you need to check the durations of calls. [Java profiling - how can I get a method by method analysis of my application?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2267594/876298)

Comment: BTW, Do you have the same problem without using DynamicReports API?

Comment: @AlexK I didn't not check that much actually. It runs slow if dependencies are within jar and runs ok if dependencies are outside. looks like it takes time to unpack jar and load.